# Forcing gdal_retile to produce full tiles when original file's size is incompatible?

Tags: gdal, tiles, extents, osgeo4w

I have a set of large geotiff (DEM + orthoimagery) that I need to generate image pyramids from. So far `gdal_retile` from osgeo4w is working very well for my use case with one exception:  I need all my tiles to be of uniform pixel size (eg: 1025x1025). `gdal_retile` will, as its default behavior, produce smaller tiles at the edges if the original file's pixel dimensions are not a multiple of the tile size.

Alternatively, is there a gdal command that will let me pad the DEM and orthoimagery with 'empty' / 'transparent' data out to an even multiple of my tile size)?

Comment: hello, did you figure this out?

Comment: Nope. I ended up zero-padding the data myself in the importer I wrote for the tool I was using.